# Define which Endpoint to use when consuming a Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm new to .NET and have been following this tutorial (http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/) to consume a simple weather web service. My small console application essentially asks the user for a ZIP code, fires that to the web service then returns to response in the console. At least, that's the way it should work.

The web service I am using is: 
http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx

The problem with this is there are multiple endpoints for different ways of consuming the service:

- SOAP 1.1
- SOAP 1.2
- HTTP GET
- HTTP POST

Because of this, when I run the console application, I am presented with the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: An endpoint configuration section for contract 'Service1Reference.WeatherSoap'
could not be loaded because more than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found. Please indicate the preferred endpoint configuration section by name.
```

My question is, how do I specify that my call to the web service should use one of the SOAP endpoints?
My code so far can be found below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ConsoleApplication1.Service1Reference;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.Write("Enter ZipCode: ");
      var line = Console.ReadLine();
      if (line == null)
      {
        return;
      }

      WeatherSoapClient svc = null;
      bool success = false;
      try
      {
        svc = new WeatherSoapClient();

        var request = line;
        var result = svc.GetCityForecastByZIP(request);

        Console.WriteLine("The result is:");
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.Write("ENTER to continue:");
        Console.ReadLine();

        svc.Close();
        success = true;
      }
      finally
      {
        if (!success && svc != null)
        {
          svc.Abort();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

The contents of my App.config file can be found here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WeatherSoap" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="WeatherSoap12">
                    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
                    <httpTransport />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="WeatherSoap12"
                contract="Service1Reference.WeatherSoap" name="WeatherSoap12" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you have an `app.config` with a `system.serviceModel` entry? From the error it seems like you have too much information in your config

Comment: @DaveParsons I do indeed. There is a basicHTTPBinding and a customBinding. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Could you edit your question and include that section of the config?

Comment: Please find the edit above. I tried removing one of the Endpoints under client but now I get a different error regarding no endpoint listening at the target URL.

Comment: Added an answer, you'll need to put that endpoint back into the config. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though .NET is trying to be helpful in generating a SOAP 1.2 binding for you when you probably don't need it (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679641/update-service-reference-insist-on-adding-soap12-to-config) for more information).

To work around this you can explicitly tell the service client which binding to use when you instantiate it by specifying the endpoint name to use:

```
svc = new WeatherSoapClient("WeatherSoap");
```

Where `"WeatherSoap"` is the value of the `name` attribute on your `endpoint` node.

Comment: Great. Thanks for this. That seems to actually return something without error now even if it is just: ConsoleApplication1.Service1Reference.ForecastReturn . The problem is I don't know why it's not actually returning the value of any of the nodes in the XML returned or indeed the actual XML response. Am I missing something?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on this line `var result = svc.GetCityForecastByZIP(request);` and inspect the `result` object. It should contain all the information from the web service call.

Comment: I think it's simpler than that. In Visual Studio if I type result. it comes up with all of the options that are available to be returned.

Comment: Actually looking at it, that's not the case. I though that using result.Temperature would allow me to display the temperature but apparently Forecast return doesn't contain a definition for temperature.

Comment: @jezzipin: Experiment, research, debug, pull some hair out, repeat and if you still are having issues then I'd say open a new question :)